# What should I put at laravel passport refresh token?

Tags: laravel

trying to find a solution for refresh token.

```php
public function refresh()
{
   $http = new Client();

   $response = $http->post('http://localhost/my_project/public/oauth/token', [
              'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type'    => 'refresh_token',
                    'client_id' => 1,
                    'client_secret' => '*******',
                    'refresh_token' => '',
                    'scope'         => '*',
                ],
            ]);

   $data = json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);

   return [
      'access_token' => $data['access_token'],
      'expires_in'   => $data['expires_in']       
   ];
}
```

But I don't know what to put at refresh token. Can somebody help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

When `http://localhost/my_project/public/oauth/token` is first called for the authorization_code, a refresh_token will be returned. This is what you need to provide for the `refresh_token` form parameter.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#refreshing-tokens

Comment: What payload are you sending with the POST request?

Comment: Content-Type , Authorization

Comment: Okay, as I said please take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#refreshing-tokens as it sounds like you are not providing all of the required data. If you could update your question to provide some code, that would be a big help.

P.S. Please remove any sensitive information that may be within your code when you post.

Comment: Hi Alex, yeah I have read the doc, but still, I stuck. I have no idea what other code I should add. I just want to generate a refresh token, but I get that I am not Authorized.

Comment: Now I get this error: The refresh token is invalid.","hint":"Cannot decrypt the refresh token" (truncated...)